# Difference between 2 identical codes

Tags: python, django, cmd, windows-10, atom-editor

I'm am trying to troubleshoot an HTTP response one code works fine but, the other one is returning an ValueError they are the both same code and I looked over them for 1hr side by side but, I can't find what is wrong with the bad code this is really bugging me.

***Working code:***`

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import auth

def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
            try:
                user = User.object.get(username=request.POST['username'])
                return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'error':'Username in use'})
            except User.DoesNotExist:
                User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
                auth.login(request.user)
                return redirect('home')
    else:
        return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')

def logout(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')
```

***BAD CODE:***

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import auth

def signup(request):
 if request.method =='POST':
    if request.POST['password1'] == request.POST['password2']:
        try:
            user = User.object.get(username=request.POST['username'])
            return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html', {'error':'Username in use '})
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            User.objects.create_user(request.POST['username'], password=request.POST['password1'])
            auth.login(request.user)
            return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')

def login(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/login.html')

def logout(request):
    return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')
```

`

Comment: you indentation is incorrect in second code, first code is able to handle get request where as second is not

Comment: Your indentations are off. There are difference checker commands you can use in shell for this and here's an online tool.

https://www.diffchecker.com/diff

Comment: That's very odd because, I usually get an indentations error but, this one was ValueError HTTP response  and atom does highlight purple for acceptable syntax so, I guess. I over looked that also, thanks for pointing me to diffchecker this will help a ton on future issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/signup.html')
```

So this piece of code if it's not a post, but a GET request in the first piece of code it will return the web page signup.html. But in the second the else statement isn't even under an if.